# Python using local files rather than a url argument

Tags: python, google-vision

I'm playing around with the google vision ai to learn python and I was wondering how I could get this code to run with a local image as at the moment you have to run "python code.py URL argument". How could I make it load a file in a local directory?

```
import argparse
import io

from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types


def annotate(path):
    """Returns web annotations given the path to an image."""
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    if path.startswith('http') or path.startswith('gs:'):
        image = types.Image()
        image.source.image_uri = path

    else:
        with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
            content = image_file.read()

        image = types.Image(content=content)

    web_detection = client.web_detection(image=image).web_detection

    return web_detection


    def report(annotations):
        """Prints detected features in the provided web annotations."""
        if annotations.pages_with_matching_images:
            print('\n{} Pages with matching images retrieved'.format(
                len(annotations.pages_with_matching_images)))

        for page in annotations.pages_with_matching_images:
            print('Url   : {}'.format(page.url))

    if annotations.full_matching_images:
        print('\n{} Full Matches found: '.format(
              len(annotations.full_matching_images)))

        for image in annotations.full_matching_images:
            print('Url  : {}'.format(image.url))

    if annotations.partial_matching_images:
        print('\n{} Partial Matches found: '.format(
              len(annotations.partial_matching_images)))

        for image in annotations.partial_matching_images:
            print('Url  : {}'.format(image.url))

    if annotations.web_entities:
        print('\n{} Web entities found: '.format(
              len(annotations.web_entities)))

        for entity in annotations.web_entities:
            print('Score      : {}'.format(entity.score))
            print('Description: {}'.format(entity.description))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    path_help = str('The image to detect, can be web URI, '
                    'Google Cloud Storage, or path to local file.')
    parser.add_argument('image_url', help=path_help)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    report(annotate(args.image_url))
```

I've tried changing a lot of things but whatever happens it still asks for an argument, is this a stipulation from the google api? I thought it had local support based on the code already but I can't figure out for the life of my what the trigger is. Any time I try to run the could without a URL argument it throws this error my way.

" usage: visiontest.py [-h] image_url visiontest.py: error: too few arguments"

Comment: It looks to me like this code already has local file support.

Comment: can you fix the code indentation? Also, do you have an error? Which line raises the error and what is the error message?

Comment: I thought it had local support too but I cant figure out for the life of my what the trigger is. Any time I try to run the could without a URL argument it throws this error my way. "
usage: visiontest.py [-h] image_url
visiontest.py: error: too few arguments"

Comment: indentation is fixed

Comment: instead of a URL, did you pass a file path? it's not clear what you're asking. You're not telling us which line throws the error. you're not telling us how you're running the code, etc.

Comment: To echo @DavidZemens, you still have to pass an argument, so the code knows where to look for the image file. If the argument you pass doesn't start with something URL-like, then it should search the system for that path.

Comment: Sorry, still new to this. I'm running it from the python command line. I did use a file path and that worked, thanks! "python visiontest.py static/image.jpg" any idea how I could hardcode the file path within the code rather than passing the argument with the command line?

Comment: Instead of `report(annotate(args.image_url))`, do `report(annotate(r'path/to/file.jpg'))`. The argument you pass is a string, so, instead of passing the `args.image_url`, just pass the string literal instead.